# Redirect stdin/stdout in sbt run task

Tags: scala, sbt

Is there any way to redirect stdin/stdout for the sbt `run` task? I can do it from the Bash shell like this:

```
sbt run < myfile.txt
```

But not from the sbt console. This doesn't work, for instance:

```
> run < myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom `runWithInput` task which does this for you by running a new JVM process with the input redirected from an argument file.
See https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Process and https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Getting-Started-Custom-Settings.

Comment: Ouch! Yes, clearly I can do this, but I was rather hoping that there would be a standard way that didn't involve this level of hackery. I guess not :-(

Comment: I'm not sure if SBT runs a new process when you invoke `run` - I think it just creates a new classloader with the compiled classes and runs from the same JVM. Not sure if it's possible to redirect standard input in the existing JVM.

Comment: @axel22 - See `System.setOut` - it is indeed possible, I even used that for unit-testing output once. But still, that would require custom task.

Comment: You mean `System.setIn`? Yeah, that's possible.